# NAND operator in R

Tags: r, operators

Is there a 'proper' NAND operator in R ie something like

```
nand(condition1, condition 2)
```

or is it simply best practise/the only possibility to do

```
!(condition1 & condition2)
```

What other options are there?

Comment: You could define your own. The options built in to base are all documented at `?Logic` (also accessible via `?"&"`, `?"|"`, or `?"!"`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of resolving this, there is no built in `nand` function in R, and the only way I can think of to improve your proposed `!(x & y)` is to move this operation to a compiled language, e.g.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector nand(Rcpp::LogicalVector lhs, Rcpp::LogicalVector rhs) {
  R_xlen_t i = 0, n = lhs.size();
  Rcpp::LogicalVector result(n);

  for ( ; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = !(lhs[i] && rhs[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

/*** R

Lhs <- rbinom(10e4, 1, .5)
Rhs <- rbinom(10e4, 1, .5)

r_nand <- function(x, y) !(x & y)

all.equal(nand(Lhs, Rhs), r_nand(Lhs, Rhs))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  nand(Lhs, Rhs), r_nand(Lhs, Rhs),
  times = 200L)
#Unit: microseconds
#            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  nand(Lhs, Rhs)  716.140  749.926 1215.353  771.015 1856.734  6332.284   200
#r_nand(Lhs, Rhs) 3337.494 3397.809 5106.614 3461.845 4985.807 95226.834   200

*/
```

---

Whether or not this is worth the trouble likely depends on how often you need to call `nand`. For the majority of purposes, the above `r_nand` should suffice. In fact, `base::xor` is implemented similarly:

```
base::xor
#function (x, y) 
#{
#  (x | y) & !(x & y)
#}
#<bytecode: 0x2fbbb90>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: @jenesaisquoi No it's virtually the same - a couple of microseconds faster than `r_nand`.

Comment: No NA handling in the cpp implementation, `identical(nand(NA, TRUE), r_nand(NA, TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you, and yes, since it does not implement all of the features of `!(x & y)` - such as element recycling for unequal-length vectors - it probably gains a bit of a performance edge as a result. But then again, I'm not sure I agree R's treatment of `NA`s in this situation: `!(NA & FALSE)` returns `TRUE` and `!(NA & TRUE)` returns `NA`. I think it would be more sensible, and consistent, to return `NA` in both cases.

Comment: Logically, NA & FALSE is certainly FALSE (NA could be TRUE or FALSE, but that doesn't change the fact that the second operand is FALSE). NA & TRUE is another story -- if NA where TRUE, then we'd have TRUE, but if NA were FALSE, then we'd have FALSE, so since we don't know the logical value of NA, we don't know the outcome. R is logically correct, even if it doesn't seem sensible! I think your code could implement recycling and NA  (I'm not enough of an Rcpp aficionado to know for sure, but I think there are formulations where this will work 'out of the box').

Comment: I don't know if this is any better, but another option is to define a `nand` operator: `\`%nand%\` <- function(x,y) !(x & y)` that could be used like this: `a %nand% b`. (FYI, it returns `NA` if one of the arguments is `NA` and the other is `TRUE` or `NA`.)